# Why am I getting a No interface method complete in class CompletableJob Exception

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, kotlin-coroutines

I'm getting this error when running a unit test on a composable:

```
No interface method complete()Z in class Lkotlinx/coroutines/CompletableJob; or its super classes (declaration of 'kotlinx.coroutines.CompletableJob' appears in /data/app/~~fIPCXqaEQds-4dojIoIsag==4dojIoIsag==/com.fluffypants.rockhard==/base.apk!classes2.dex
```

It's throwing it on this line in IdlingResourceRegistry.jvm.kt:

```
private var pollJob: Job = Job().also { it.complete() }
```

This is the upstream code that I'm running that ultimately leads to the line that errors.  It breaks on createComposeRule():

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4:class
class MyInstrumentedTest{
    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
@Test
    fun myTest() = runTest {
        //errors no matter what I put in here
    }
}
```

I have these test libraries configured in my build.gradle

```
testImplementation "junit:junit:4.13.2"
androidTestImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.7.1"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4-android:1.6.3"
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:1.6.3"
```

I'm using the most up to date versions of all of the test libraries.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please share your test otherwise will be difficult to help out

Comment: I have commented out the entire test other than the line I gave and still receive the error:  val composeTestRule = createComposeRule().  I'll update the rest shortly.

Comment: not able to replicate the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the issue was that 'minifyEnabled' was set to 'true' in my buildType variant configuration.

So for example, my buildType was configured like this:

```
android{
    buildTypes{
        myBuildTypeName{
            shrinkResources false
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.lle
        }
    }
}
```

Just changing the value for 'minifyEnabled' to 'false' resolved the issue for me.